# Where is a reputable place to download Ultimaker Cura?

Tags: ultimaker-cura

I noticed that my version of Ultimaker Cura was out of date, so I tried to go to [their website](https://ultimaker.com) and download a new version.  For whatever reason, I could not get the [download link](https://ultimaker.com/en/products/ultimaker-cura-software/download-request/191) to work properly in Firefox with a slew of security extensions.

Where are reputable mirrors for Cura?

Download.Cnet.com and Sourceforge [came up as sources](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=download%20cura&t=ffsb&ia=web), but years ago they both [went to the darkside](http://insecure.org/news/download-com-fiasco.html) (SourceForge: [HowToGeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/218764/warning-don%E2%80%99t-download-software-from-sourceforge-if-you-can-help-it/), [thecomputerpeeps](https://thecomputerpeeps.com/2013/08/sourceforge-malware/)).  I don't see anything else that looks even remotely reputable in the search results.

I did some analysis, and it appears that the drop down and form don't work correctly if you select "I don't want to share any personal information", leading me to think this is web page bug.

Comment: If one of your security extensions is blocking you from downloading software from the publisher's own site then either disable the extension (maybe temporarily) or look for alternative software -- you are always less secure downloading from unauthorized 3rd party mirrors because a good mirror site will have a copy of the original (including anything bad that might be in it) and a bad mirror can add malware of it's own - a mirror will never remove bad staff from the original but can add new bad stuff -- don't make yourself less secure just to please security software

Comment: I believe, it is the security extensions borking up. Disable them for the ultimaker site.

Comment: Reaction on the edit: I always choose that option, but I do get the DL link after that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer to your question is: **"From the application developer itself!"**.

Below is the explanation how you can (directly) download Ultimaker Cura from the most reputable source: Ultimaker.com

---

### Regular download

When clicking the [link to download](http://ultimaker.com/en/products/ultimaker-cura-software/list) of the Cura application download button from the [Ultimaker website](https://ultimaker.com/en/products/ultimaker-cura-software) you are presented with a pop-up GUI that asks you if you want to share where you are using the program for. When you select the required field and press download, the download starts. If this doesn't work, a direct download approach can be used.

### Direct download

If the regular download method fails, or you do not get the pop-up GUI, you can use the direct link for Ultimaker Cura from the developer's website:

https://download.ultimaker.com/cura/Ultimaker_Cura-4.1.0-win64.exe

<strike>This link can be found at the download directory at the website:</strike>

https://download.ultimaker.com/current/

This web directory overview also shows all previous releases and installers for other platforms.

As of version 3.6.0, the download does not appear to be in the list, this link will show an overview: https://ultimaker.com/en/products/ultimaker-cura-software/list
Do note that the latter link will show the pop-up.

*As of version 4.1, the web directory overview link will serve a 404.*

#### Github

The Ultimaker Cura Project has a Github, where they offer the current and previous editions under:

https://github.com/Ultimaker/Cura/tags

Answer (score 0):

Cura is a software tool developed by Ultimaker for 3D printers. There is a downloadable page for this tool: https://ultimaker.com/en/products/ultimaker-cura-software/list. There is no restriction to download it.

I'm using Firefox on all my PC's and it can be downloaded with no problems, even if I'm using Windows XP, the main PC works at full speed with 3D models.

Comment: This shows the list, but is not a direct download link to the file, there is a GUI interface between that page and the actual download, this is probably why the OP is not able to download the file